# How to get concrete element by jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like:

```
if($(this).hasClass("playButton"))
    {
        $(this).find("li").removeClass("active");
    }
```

But instead of "this" in "if" statement I want to use any class selector. But I don't know how to get concrete DOM element, which corresponds to the condition.
So I need:

```
if($(.anyClass).hasClass("playButton"))
    {
        $(current element, which corresponds to
        if condition).find("li").removeClass("active");            
    }
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It only takes an hour, two at the most. Also worth looking through some tutorials, and generally doing some research.

Comment: You may declare a variable for that. Just like `var current = $(this).hasClass("playButton")`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the elements using the `".anyClass"` selector and then iterate through them using `each`. In the callback function of `each`, `this` will refer to the current DOM element.

```
$(".anyClass").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("playButton")) {
    $(this).find(".btn").removeClass("playButton");            
  }
});
```

However, for this particular scenario, you can reach your goal without using `each`. Simply target the element directly and manipulate it, as [@Derek朕會功夫](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832674/1323504) suggested in his answer.

```
$(".playButton li").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: The `.each` call is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it is, in this particular case. However, the post asked for a technical question, and I answered that.

Comment: "the post asked for a technical question (answer)". Well, I don't think so, I don't even consider the question to be technical. The question shows that he/she doesn't understand the basics of DOM/jQuery and it resulted in asking a confusing question.

Comment: I don't think this argument leads to anything constructive. This is a matter of viewpoint or flavor I think. My answer is still valid, and can teach him/her some things. So is Derek 朕會功夫's answer.

Comment: Just in case of future edits, here is a quote which I based my answer on: "But I don't know how to get concrete DOM element, which corresponds to the condition". So I ment to answer that in first place, regardless of being optimal for this particular context.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".playButton li").removeClass("active");
```

...?

Comment: The answer must be something simple as that.

Comment: Indeed this is equivalent, however this doesn't answer the question directly in my opinion, just gives a shorter and more elegant alternative.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Well if it's equivalent, then that implies it also solves the exact same set of problems.

Comment: @AKS Updated to use the new class names.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 you are both right, this is a subjective point. I prefer giving an exact technical answer to a technical question, but I'll include this in my answer too as a suggestion for this particular scenario.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I mean it's obvious that OP is new to jQuery, and I believe the answer should point him to the right way of using the library instead of something very complicated yet still does the same thing.

Comment: I thought the question was about how to refer to the selected DOM elements. Of course in the current context of this question your answer is completely right. But I ment to answer what I understood in general. You'll get my upvote.